# Finding Area of a Quadrilateral

Tags: quadrilateral

Can someone please help me through this problem? I am not even really sure where I should start.

Quadrilateral ABCD has vertices A(-2,-2), B(1,4), C(8,4), D(5,2). Find the area of the quadrilateral, round your answer to the nearest tenth if necessary.

Comment: What kind of quadrilateral is this? What are the side lengths?

Comment: That is the problem that I am having. That is all the information that is given.

Comment: [Shoelace theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem) problem!

Comment: Try drawing a diagram and see if you can split it into two triangles.

Comment: @IHeartBunnies you were given four points. Just plot them on a graph and see what they look like. Then use the coordinates of the points and the distance formula to compute the side lengths.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I didn't even think about that.

Comment: My teacher wouldn't let us use a graph, but I see how you could use the distance formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Partition your polygon so that you get a trapezoid and a triangle, like below.

[image]

Then apply your formulas for area of a triangle and area of a trapezoid.